# How do i use "select" for a datatable with "not in (a subquery)"

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

I want to execute this query on datatable `dt1`:

```
select * from dt1 where col1 NOT IN(select col1 from dt2)
```

**here's the test code:**

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    Dim dt3 As New DataTable
    dt1.Columns.Add("col1")
    dt1.Columns.Add("col2")
    dt1.Columns.Add("col3")
    dt1.Rows.Add("1", "a", "a")
    dt1.Rows.Add("2", "b", "b")
    dt1.Rows.Add("3", "c", "c")
    dt1.Rows.Add("4", "d", "d")
    dt1.Rows.Add("5", "e", "e")

    dt2.Columns.Add("col1")
    dt2.Columns.Add("col4")
    dt2.Columns.Add("col5")
    dt2.Rows.Add("1", "a", "a")
    dt2.Rows.Add("2", "f", "f")
    dt2.Rows.Add("3", "g", "g")

    dt3.Columns.Add("col1")
    dt3.Columns.Add("col2")
    dt3.Columns.Add("col3")

    'Dim rows() As DataRow = dt1.Select("dt1.select(columns(0)) Not In (dt2.select(cloumns(0)))")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx) method. Example:

```
dt2.AsEnumerable.Except(dt1.AsEnumerable, DataRowComparer.Default)
```

Depending on what you consider "not being in Dt2" you might need to define your custom [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I want to add those rows in dt3, which are in dt1 but not in dt2. I can't think of how to use IEqualityComparer for this task as I'm quite new. Can you help on this?

Comment: baed on "col1" as primary key for both.

Comment: Having the results in dt3 is a different question than what you asked. The IEqualityComparer is only the "compare strategy" for determining which rows are equal to each other, and DataRowComparer.Default is an implementation of it, and that is already doing what you want (comparing by the first "column"). For your other question, check [Creating a datatable from a query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: __hint: CopyToDataTable()__

Comment: @SagarVerma did you find my answer useful? or do you need more help?